# Update helm Release on changes to values file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, flux

I'm trying to deploy an application from a helm chart with flux, to which i only need to add my `values.yaml` file. So I have :

- a `HelmRepository` pointing to the publicly available chart
- A `HelmRelease` created with the flux ci, where the values file is directly available on the command line.

That works.
But i would like to have a git repository with the values.yaml file that is watched by flux for changes, and then the release get's updated.

Is that possible?

I specifically want to keep the `values.yaml` file independent of flux, as it can be used in other deployments that don't include flux. I know i could 'type it 'directly in the `HelmRelease` but that's what i don't want.